# Changing cursor speed inside a div tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor

I want to change the cursor speed inside some div tags, to give a better user experience in my web site. I have already changed the image of the cursor, I want to change slow down the cursor. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I'm highly skeptical messing with the cursor speed could improve the UX, even if it were possible.

Comment: You can do some hack but it will not works exactly the way you want - I mean, you can delay the cursor icon but not the **actual** cursor (at least in the I think about - mabey there is another way..)

Comment: Just to throw this out here. I got intrigued by this subject and tried out the pointer lock API which was mentioned down in the comments of another answer and made up a simple demo with it here: http://codepen.io/thepio/pen/RRBzrP?editors=1010 (using jQuery). Unfortunately it seems like (at least I couldn't make it work) you can't initiate the pointer lock with `mouseenter` or `hover` or anything like that. Only a click event seems to work. Maybe I will examine this more when I have time but it's an interesting concept.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think this is possible to control the cursor with Javascript. But you could, however, hide the cursor using

```css
cursor: none;
```

and then do some JavaScript to emulate a slower moving cursor made with HTML/CSS. But this would be much more work than it is worth, and probably wouldn't work out very well anyway.

Comment: Seeing as the real cursor would still move normally, it would probably exit the area unexpectedly.

Comment: `@Alexander O'Mara` you could test for the Element's position that you have moving around the screen. You'll want to use the Event Object to test for `event.cliientX` and `event.clientY` against your `Element.getBoundingClientRect()`, or something else to see where your cursor is.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this using pure javascript might be a challenge but you can try incorporating this feature slowing down the cursor's speed while holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> using the [AutoHotKey script](http://steamcommunity.com/app/367670/discussions/0/620712999975811863/).

You need AutoHotKey installed to perform this but it's free and open-source.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly control the pointer speed via any DOM API, nor do I expect such an API will become available due to accessibility issues and probable click-jacking abuse.

That being said, in many modern browsers there is an API called [Pointer Lock](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_Lock_API), where you can request control over pointer movements. Using this, you could emulate a slower cursor by taking over the cursor movements and positioning a fake cursor.